# Issues with iOS 17 and Keyboardavoidingview & email type input

Tags: ios, react-native

Since updating to iOS 17, I am having issues where the keyboard flickers.  My simulator is still on iOS 16 and I am not seeing that issue.

[image]

If I remove Keyboardavoidingview, the Passwords helper above the keys still flickers

It seems limited to the "email" type inputs, so I tried changing the keyboardType but no change.

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
      // keyboardVerticalOffset={100} // toggling no change
      style={{ justifyContent: 'space-between', height: '100%' }}
    >
      <View>
        <TextInput
            autoCapitalize="none"
            errorMessage={fieldState.error ? 'Invalid email' : undefined}
            errorStyle={styles.error}
            // keyboardType="email-address" // toggling no change
            label="Email Address"
            onBlur={field.onBlur}
            onChangeText={field.onChange}
            placeholder="Email"
            returnKeyType="next"
            value={field.value}
          />
      </View>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

My iOS simulator is still on iOS16 and seems to have no issue.

Any ideas?